# Change background color JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using JavaScript and I am beginner. I want to change the background color using the button. And after that click again to change it back to the previous color.
Here my code :

```js
const cColor = document.getElementById("cColor");
cColor.onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <h1>Change Backgroud Color</h1>
  <button type="button" id="cColor">Button</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make this a little easier on yourself - by not manipulating inline styles; but by using a class in your stylesheet to apply the different color, and then simply using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier with classNames but if you want to do it modifying the background color with js, here you have a possible solution:

```js
 const cColor = document.getElementById("cColor");
  cColor.onclick = function () {
if (document.body.id === "active") {
  document.body.id = "";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
} else {
  document.body.id = "active";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";
}
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Change Backgroud Color</h1>
    <button type="button" id="cColor">Button</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With classname:

```js
  const cColor = document.getElementById("cColor");
  cColor.onclick = function () {
document.body.classList.toggle("active");
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }
      body.active{
         background-color: salmon;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Change Backgroud Color</h1>
    <button type="button" id="cColor">Button</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a nice separation of HTML/JS/CSS concerns here and, as CBroe pointed out in their comment, you can achieve your goal very easily with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

So, in your JS file, [grab your button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), add an [event listener to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which, when the click event is triggered, calls a function that toggles the class(es) you've defined in your CSS file.

```js
// Get the button and add a listener to it
const button = document.querySelector('#cColor');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When the click event is triggered toggle the
// red class on/off
function handleClick() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('salmon');
}
```

```css
body { background-color: lightgreen; }
.salmon { background-color: salmon; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="cColor">Change background colour</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const cColor = document.getElementById("cColor");
            let count = 0;
            cColor.onclick = function () {
                if ((count == 0)) {
                    console.log(`Zero Count : ${count}`);
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";
                    count=1;
                } else {
                    console.log(`Non Zero Count : ${count}`);
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    count=0;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script too

```js
const cColor = document.getElementById("cColor");
let bool = true
cColor.onclick = function() {
 if(bool) {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "salmon";
   bool = !bool
 }
 else{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  bool = !bool
 }
};
```